# Which android sdk class can be used for change settings like APN, E911 or CMAS

Tags: android, telephony

I would like to know if anyone can point to a good source that explain how can you can change phone carrier related settings such APN, E911 CMAS using the Android SDK. I noticed the Telephony Manager class as CarrierConfigManager, but not sure which will give read/write access or which is the best or if there any better ways to do it.

Comment: I doubt that there is any way to modify those settings via the Android SDK.

Answer (score 3):

You can change APN by using content provider provided by [Telephony.Carriers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Carriers.html).

Following is the code I used to create a new APN.

```
public void saveApn(Apn newApn) {
    String name = checkNotSet(newApn.getName());
    String apn = checkNotSet(newApn.getApn());
    String mcc = checkNotSet(newApn.getMcc());
    String mnc = checkNotSet(newApn.getMnc());

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Telephony.Carriers.NAME, name);
    values.put(Telephony.Carriers.APN, apn);

    values.put(Telephony.Carriers.MCC, mcc);
    values.put(Telephony.Carriers.MNC, mnc);
    values.put(Telephony.Carriers.NUMERIC, mcc + mnc);


    mContext.getContentResolver().insert(Telephony.Carriers.CONTENT_URI, values)
}
```

And to set as prefered APN

```
private void setAsPreferedApn(int apnId) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("apn_id", String.valueOf(apnId));
    getContentResolver().update(Uri.withAppendedPath(Telephony.Carriers.CONTENT_URI, "preferapn"), values, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, any pointer on how which Interface and Settings needs to be modified in order to implement e911?

Comment: No idea for that particular part.